# webview won't load at onClick

Tags: android, button, webview, onclick

I have 2 Buttons which load  2 difefrent html sites respectively.

```
public class Information extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button b1, b2 ;
private WebView webview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info);


    b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);


    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);


    webview=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

    });

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v){


    switch(v.getId()) {

    case R.id.b1:
        showOne();
        break;

    case R.id.b2:
        showTwo();
        break;


    }

}

public void showOne(){
    webview.loadUrl("some url");

    }

public void showTwo() { 
    webview.loadUrl("some url here");
}
```

}

this results in errors that force the application to end. 
When I remove the webview part, the buttons are desplayed, but nothing happens when I click on them. 
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check that  there are a webview named webview in R.layout.info ?

webview=(WebView) findViewById(**R.id.webview**); complier couldnt find this webview.

and try to add , com.yourpackagename.R;

Comment: oh, yeap. that was it, thanks.
but now I have another problem: the webview loads in background, so my buttons are in front...

Comment: i think you use relativelayout to wrap them. Change the order of your widget in relativelayout.

Comment: yes, but changing the order won't save the problem. I want the webview to show **after** I click on on of the buttons

Comment: in oncreate webview.setVisibility(View.GONE);  when you click button webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);